# how can I append text to docx file using node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docx

I am trying to append a text to a docx file using node I keep getting error that says word document detected some unsreasonable characters in the document after my code ran thereby unable to open the document.
Here is the code.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const faker = require('faker');

const filePath = path.resolve(
  __dirname,
  'cypress',
  'fixtures',
  'my-file.docx',
);

const docReadStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
const docWriteStream = fs.createWriteStream('./output.docx');

docReadStream.on('data', chunk => {
  console.log(typeof chunk);
  console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(chunk));
  docWriteStream.write(chunk);
});

docReadStream.on('end', () => {
  const encoder = new TextEncoder();
  const lulu = faker.random.alphaNumeric(100);
  const getti = encoder.encode(lulu);
  docWriteStream.write(getti, 'binary', err => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log('no error');
    }
  });
});
```

am producing an output but unable to view the output

Comment: Often when word docs can't open is because the XML is  wrong. You have to be specific when you want to edit a word document with code. Try this library. https://www.npmjs.com/package/docx